# Scroll editor in Xamarin Forms into view

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using Xamarin Forms, consider the Xaml below.

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
   <Image x:Name="cameraImage" Source="camera.png" />
   <Label Text="Describe the image" />
   <Editor />
   <Button Text="Save" />
 </StackLayout>
```

This renders an image, an editor and a save button. The image is in 4x3 image ratio and covers about a third of the available screen height. The editor is rendered below.

The problem is that the keyboard covers the Editor in iOS. A standard iOS issue normally.

The question is: What is the Xamarin Forms way of handling this?

Thanks

// Johan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get auto scroll for Editors and Entries with Xamarin.Forms, you usually just have to pack your View, in this case the StackLayout, into a ScrollView:

```xaml
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Image x:Name="cameraImage" Source="camera.png" />
        <Label Text="Describe the image" />
        <Editor />
        <Button Text="Save" />
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

That's how it's supposed to work, but as of today (June 2014) there's a bug preventing this to work fully with the Editor (it works well with Entries). The issue is known and is worked on.

[UPDATE 2014-11-20]The issue has been addressed, and will be available in the next -pre release of XF 1.3

Comment: This wont work well if you have a listview inside. Mixing scrollviews with listviews will mess up the drag event

Comment: like @NavySeal and Falko wrote - it's not a best practice to embed scroll inside the scroll (not only in Forms). This won't work for non-standard keyboards like emoji or 3rd party (like SwiftKey)

Answer (score 12):

I just stumbled upon this question when writing a tiny chat application, which basically contains a scrollable message list, a text entry and a send button:

[image]
[image]

The problem with the previously posted solution is that you'd need to nest two scroll views, which is not recommended by the [Xamarin.Forms documentation](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AXamarin.Forms.ScrollView). To prevent the keyboard from hiding the entry, I found the following hack:

I'm adding a `placeholder` at the end of the main stack layout. Depending on whether the entry is focussed (i.e. the keyboard is visible or not) the height of the placeholder is set to 0 or the keyboard height.

```
        // HACK: make entry visible when keyboard open
        var placeholder = new BoxView {
            HeightRequest = 0,
        };
        entry.Focused += (sender, e) => placeholder.HeightRequest = 210;
        entry.Unfocused += (sender, e) => placeholder.HeightRequest = 0;

        Content = new StackLayout {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
            Padding = 5,
            Children = {
                whoTable,
                messageScrollView,
                new StackLayout {
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
                    HeightRequest = 70,
                    Children = {
                        entry,
                        sendButton,
                    },
                },
                placeholder,
            },
        };
```

Of course, this is not perfect. Especially the hard-coded keyboard height should be implemented more elegantly. And probably you should apply it on iOS only, not on Android.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you cannot put your main view in a scrollview, in those cases you can implement this by handling the keyboard events the iOS project and passing them to the Forms level. Android takes care of it's self.

```
using System;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using RaiseKeyboard.iOS;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (KeyboardHelper))]
namespace RaiseKeyboard.iOS
{
    // Raises keyboard changed events containing the keyboard height and
    // whether the keyboard is becoming visible or not
    public class KeyboardHelper : IKeyboardHelper
    {
        public KeyboardHelper() {
            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIKeyboard.WillHideNotification, OnKeyboardNotification);
            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIKeyboard.WillShowNotification, OnKeyboardNotification);
        }

        public event EventHandler<KeyboardHelperEventArgs> KeyboardChanged;

        private void OnKeyboardNotification (NSNotification notification)
        {
            var visible = notification.Name == UIKeyboard.WillShowNotification;
            var keyboardFrame = visible
                ? UIKeyboard.FrameEndFromNotification(notification)
                : UIKeyboard.FrameBeginFromNotification(notification);
            if (KeyboardChanged != null) {
                KeyboardChanged (this, new KeyboardHelperEventArgs (visible, (float)keyboardFrame.Height));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then at the Forms level:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace RaiseKeyboard
{
    // Provides static access to keyboard events
    public static class KeyboardHelper
    {
        private static IKeyboardHelper keyboardHelper = null;

        public static void Init() {
            if (keyboardHelper == null) {
                keyboardHelper = DependencyService.Get<IKeyboardHelper>();
            }
        }

        public static event EventHandler<KeyboardHelperEventArgs> KeyboardChanged {
            add {
                Init();
                keyboardHelper.KeyboardChanged += value;
            }
            remove {
                Init ();
                keyboardHelper.KeyboardChanged -= value;
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IKeyboardHelper
    {
        event EventHandler<KeyboardHelperEventArgs> KeyboardChanged;
    }

    public class KeyboardHelperEventArgs : EventArgs 
    {
        public readonly bool Visible;
        public readonly float Height;

        public KeyboardHelperEventArgs(bool visible, float height) {
            Visible = visible;
            Height = height;
        }
    }

}
```

If you are working in a Stacklayout and wish to raise the view above the keyboard you can put a spacer with a height 0 at the bottom of the stack. Then set it to the height of the keyboard when the keyboard changed event is raised.

```
spacer.HeightRequest = e.Visible ? e.Height : 0;
```

If you are working with a Listview you can handle this by translating your view by the amount it would have been overlapped by.

```
bottomOffset = mainStack.Bounds.Bottom - textStack.Bounds.Bottom;
textStack.TranslationY -= e.Visible ? e.Height - bottomOffset : bottomOffset - e.Height;
```

Listviews have to be handled differently as there height is automatically adjusted by Forms and using a spacer results over correction.

Sample here: https://github.com/naturalistic/raisekeyboard

Comment: Very nice solution Daniel

Comment: This is a great solution. However it doesn't account for hardware keyboards being present. :-\

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the answer from @Falko, you can check the platform for iOS since Android handles this as expected natively.

I also added this to the page for quick and dirty orientation via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27805269/12919).

```
static bool IsPortrait(Page p) { return p.Width < p.Height; }
```

Anyway, I understand that Xamarin are adding some solutions for this soon.  For now, though...

```
protected async void Message_Focused(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
    {
        //TLR: still need a way to determine the iOS keyboard's height first
        //until then, this is a functional hack

        if (IsPortrait(this))
        {
            KeyboardSpacer.HeightRequest = 165;
        }
        else
        {
            KeyboardSpacer.HeightRequest = 114;
        }
    }
}

protected async void Message_Unfocused(object sender, EventArgs args)
{            
    if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
    {
        KeyboardSpacer.HeightRequest = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, the `raisekeyboard` was just implemented for one entry in the application, if you add a new Entry, the `KeyboardHelper.KeyboardChanged` is going to shoot, when the focus is in any entry.

```
KeyboardHelper.KeyboardChanged += (sender, e) =>{
    bottomOffset = this.ParentView.Bounds.Bottom - _editor.Bounds.Bottom;
    if (KeyboardStatus)
        _editor.TranslationY = e.Visible ? -(e.Height - bottomOffset) : 0;
    else
        _editor.TranslationY = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ScrollView as mentioned above fixes problem in iOS and partially fixes in Android. To fully fix problem in android, I found another simple and nice addition.

Only in android I replace Xamarin forms Editor with android specific TextEdit control. So in my Page constructor I have following code just for android.

```
#if __ANDROID__
         // I have editor defined in xaml named ReportTextEditor in stacklayout named MainStackLayout
        Editor sharedEditor = this.ReportTextEditor;
        MainStackLayout.Children.Remove(sharedEditor); //removing the ReportTextEditor which was defined in xaml
        EditText editText = new EditText(Forms.Context); //created android specific editor
        editText.InputType = InputTypes.ClassText | InputTypes.TextFlagAutoCorrect | InputTypes.TextFlagCapSentences | InputTypes.TextFlagMultiLine; //keyboard options, optional
        MainStackLayout.Children.Add(editText); //Added android specific edit text to my stack layout

#endif
```

You also need to add android specific namespaces as needed.

```
#if __ANDROID__
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Android.Widget;
using Button = Xamarin.Forms.Button;
using Android.Text;
#endif
```