# How to check size of screen in xamarin forms and is there any way to show different layout for different orientation?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I want to show two different layout according to screen orientation of mobile phone like for vertical different and for horizontal different so is there any to do this . I am trying to get width of screen so on the base of screen i can display layout is this right way, if yes please tell how get screen size in xamarin forms or if no then suggest right way in xamarin forms cross platform application. Thanks, ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a Layout on Orientation change in Xamarin.Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969854/add-a-layout-on-orientation-change-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: thanks for reply @Rohit its working fine