# Screen rotation for specific screens in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, screen-orientation

I have tried setting this code on MainActivity.cs

```
[Activity(Label = "PG_ELearning.Droid", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

But this locked screen rotation for all the screens. I want some screens(In which I am playing video) should have landscape mode. All screens are in Xamarin PCL shared code.
I do visited these links:

http://www.appliedcodelog.com/2017/05/force-landscape-or-portrait-for-single.html

[How to detect screen orientation of the device in Xamarin.Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656761/how-to-detect-screen-orientation-of-the-device-in-xamarin-forms)

But I am not able to find the correct approach.

Comment: could it work ?

Comment: Sorry @LeoZhu-MSFT Priorities changed. I will give you my feedback by in 2-3 days

Comment: ok, good luck !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use **MessagingCenter** to send your screen direction request：

like this(for example on Android,Ios is similar to this):

in the `MainActivity`，regist `MessagingCenter`,(the name and value you could custom)

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string, int>("direction", "indext", (sender, args) => {
            switch (args)
            {
                case 0:
                    RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait; //mandatory vertical screen
                    break;
                case 1:
                    RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Unspecified;//the default value
                    break;
            }
        });
```

and in your `Pages` send message :

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
  {
       base.OnAppearing();
       MessagingCenter.Send<string, int>("direction", "indext", num);//num = 0:Mandatory vertical screen,num = 1 :restore default
  }
```